# Running this ruby script on my website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, jekyll

I want to use [this plugin](https://github.com/ericdfields/Jekyll-Dribbble-Set-Tag/blob/master/README.md) from github on my site to display my dribbble shots. I know I need to run the script on my server, but don't know how. I tried to copy the tags in but obv, that doesn't work. My bet is that I need to install the `.rb` file and run it on my server when the site loads up. I need a little help.

Forgot to mention.. Yes i am running Jekyll. I have changed my _config file but nothing seems to happen when i enter in the code and run my site. All that happen is it breaks the site and the liquid tags that were working stop working. This is the error i get Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'dribble_set' in index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the _plugins directory from that repository into the root of your jekyll directory (alongside _config.yml etc). If you already have a _plugins directory there, copy dribble_set.rb into that directory.

It sounds like you haven't done that yet, which is why it doesn't work. How is Jekyll/Liquid supposed to know about the new tag if you don't add the code for it in?

Answer (score 0):

This script is for the Jekyll site generator. Jekyll generates a static website for you, so no Ruby needs to be setup server-side.

Check out the [Jekyll Github page](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) for some examples on getting started with it.

Comment: Sorry, yes i am running Jekyll my site. I have changed my _config file but nothing seems to happen when i enter in the code and run my site. This is the error i get `Liquid Exception: Unknown tag 'dribble_set' in index.html`

Comment: Do you have a **dribbble_set.rb** file under **/app_root/plugins/**?